# How to add classes to sections with javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, tags

Is there any way to add classes with different values to my sections element by using javascript and have the classes be increment by a value of 1 for each line.

for example:

help would be much appreciated

I have tried this

const b = document.querySelector("section");

b.classList.add('thisclass1');

this seems to only add the class for my first section but it stops at the first section. I don't know how I would use this and have the code add a class to the 2nd section and 3rd section and have the class name increment the value by 1

Comment: It's unlikely that you would want classes named liked that. You'd probably want multiple classes (with meaningful names). What differentiates `thisClass1` from `thisClass2` for example?

Comment: Hi Andy thank you for your reply. I understand the reason why it would be unlikely to have classes named like that I am using the class name in the questions an example I would probably give them a proper name.

Comment: @EdwardBrito not sure why was your post closed when the link is not as exact as your  question. Anyways I think you want a function that selects elements with `querySelectorAll` which returns *NodeList* that has `.forEach` method available, so you just loop over all of these elements and use *template strings* like `elem.classList.add(`thisClass${number})` - as for the *number* here I guess you can use the *index+1* or build a number function that spits auto-incrementing  integers